# How to retrieve model column value dynamically in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have a model object.

```
print (dir(table))
['...', 'col1', 'col2', '...']

# this will output column 1 value
print (table.col1)
```

I would like to do it dynamically, for example:

```
col = 'col1'
table.col
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `getattr` when doing dynamic attribute retrieval in python:

```
col = 'col1'
getattr(table, col)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get attribute value by name use `getattr`

```
getattr(table, 'col1')
```